# Maven enforcer plugin and missing dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-enforcer-plugin, maven-lifecycle

Here is a minimal project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>enforcer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-env</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <rules>
                        <requireProperty>
                            <property>custom</property>
                            <message>You must set custom property.</message>
                        </requireProperty>
                    </rules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>enforcer-dep</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <classifier>${custom}</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

When running:

```
mvn -Dcustom=some-value validate
```

Validation goes OK.

When running:

```
mvn enforcer:enforce
```

or any phase from `validate` to `process-resources`

```
mvn validate
mvn initialize
mvn generate-sources
mvn process-sources
mvn generate-resources
mvn process-resources
```

I get expected fail with message:

```
[...]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-env) @ enforcer ---
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireProperty failed with message:
You must set custom property.
[...]
```

But when I run any other (later) phase from `compile` up to `deploy` e.g.:

```
mvn install
```

I get the error about missing dependency but there is no fail caused by enforcer plugin:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building enforcer 1.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.test:enforcer-dep:jar:${custom}:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/test/enforcer-dep/1.0.0/enforcer-dep-1.0.0-${custom}.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.983s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Nov 22 09:22:24 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/152M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project enforcer: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.test:enforcer:jar:1.0
.0: Could not transfer artifact com.test:enforcer-dep:jar:${custom}:1.0.0 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/
maven2): Illegal character in path at index 84: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/test/enforcer-dep/1.0.0/enforcer
-dep-1.0.0-${custom}.jar -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

It looks for me like enforcer plugin is not executed at all, or dependencies are checked first before project can be build when running `compile` and later phases.

But why dependencies are not checked when running up to `process-resources`?

Comment: Can you show the full pom you are using.

Comment: There is already attached full pom.

Comment: Outch oversight. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you seemed to have changed the settings of the maven installation which went wrong based on the error message:

```
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[WARNING] expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ...ever maven must make a connection to a remote s
erver.\n   |-->\n  <s... @111:5)  @ C:\programs\Maven\3\bin\..\conf\settings.xml
```

This means first clean up the conf/settings.xml file. Best is to use the default file which came via the installation. If you need to make modification do this in the users settings.xml `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` or on Windows `C:/Users/UserName/.m2/settings.xml`

Apart from that i don't know what you like to achieve by using something like this:

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.test:enforcer-dep:jar:${custom}:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/test/enforcer-dep/1.0.0/enforcer-dep-1.0.0-${custom}.jar
```

Comment: I have fixed the problem with settings.xml. As I wrote - this was not related to the problem I describe. I have edit the original question.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to use some artifact by providing its groupId or articactId or version or classifier by some property. In presented case I want to use `${custom}` property name as classifier.

Comment: Which does not make sense in relationship with Maven. What is the purpose of that?

Comment: I don't understand why are You in doubt this does not make sense. If it IS possible to use properties like `${custom}` in dependencies - then I see it usefull. If it would be prohibited with error e.g. "`Using properties in dependency entries is not allowed`" then I would understand that. But it's not.

Purpose e.g.: I have web application and 3 servers. I want to use different .war packages for every server. To determine which one I want to use property `${custom}` which creates `myapp-1.0-dev.war` with dependency inside lib `com.test:test:dev:1.0`.

Using profiles has big disadvantages

Comment: I have already achieved such design and it works very well. Previously I was using profiles but using profiles to differ configurations per environment is bad concept.

What I want to start working is enforcer. Please concentrate on this case and not on overall configuration.

Comment: Here is example link where You can see that using properties in dependencies does make sense. http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/using-different-gwt-sdk-version.html